# Can msmtp rewrite *all* recipient addresses?

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, msmtp

I'm using msmtp to deliver system email from an Ubuntu server via an SMTP account.

Can I somehow configure this setup to rewrite **all** emails to one specific **recipient address**? If so, how?

Or put differently, I don't want any arbitrary PHP script or otherwise to be able to send email to anybody that is not me. I should be the only person that receives any email generated by any script on the server. All while only using `msmtp` (not using postfix or some other server).

Comment: `set_from_header on`: “‘on’ always sets a From header and overrides any existing one.” https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html

Comment: I’m seeking a similar option for `to` headers?

Comment: What do you mean? Reading `To:` headers is not the default behaviour anyway. Just don't pass `-t` (`--read-recipients`) when invoking `msmtp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `msmtp`.  From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/msmtp.1.html) (emphasis mine)

> Msmtp transmits mails **unaltered** to the SMTP server, with the
> following exceptions:
>
> - The   Bcc   header(s)  will  be  removed.  This  behavior  can  be  changed  with  the remove_bcc_headers command and --remove-bcc-headers
>   option.
> - A From header will be added if the mail does not have one. This can be changed with  the set_from_header  command  and  --set-from-header
>   option.  The header will use the envelope from address and optionally
>   a full name set with the -F option.
> - A Date header will be added if the mail does not have one. This can be changed with  the set_date_header command and --set-date-header
>   option.
> - When undisclosed_recipients is set, the original To, Cc, and Bcc headers are removed and replaced with "To: undisclosed-recipients:;".

The `undisclosed_recipients` features was added recently.  It does not appear to alter delivery though.

If you only cared about all **local** addresses being sent to a specific recipient (e.g. admin@domain.example) then you could use the `aliases` option with file contents

```
default: admin@domain.example
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found seen part of the man page, I think you've nailed it. I have my local aliases being rewritten, but scripts can still send mail to anywhere they want which is what I want to stop, I'll find another way.